# Fail Azure DevOps Release if any warnings found

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I recently noticed that while my release looks like it was successful, there were warnings when transforming my web.config file.  The IIS Web App Deploy task seems to report "Success" even with warnings.  Which in this case, is actually a pretty serious deployment issue and should not be a "Success".  In other tasks when warnings occur I've used a custom condition "ne(variables['Agent.JobStatus'], 'Succeeded')" to "exit 1" in a script.

The IIS Web App Deploy task seems to report "Success" even when there are warnings.  Is there anyway to detect any warnings that occur in a pipeline and fail the job?

I've also tried using the "Build Quality Checks" extension which doesn't seem to work in a release pipeline.  I get this warning from that task "##[warning]This task cannot be run in a multi-config build on TFS 2015. Execution aborted."

[image: Warning Example]

I'd like to have a final task that is capable of detecting any warnings that occur and marking the release as failed.